# reset ui value in Matlab GUI before changing to new value

Tags: matlab, reset, matlab-guide

So far, just say that I have a GUI and list of uicontrol in it with 1 push button that start the computation process. In the push button, the callback function look like this :

```
% --- Executes on button press in mulai.
function mulai_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to mulai (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%--give the program "Working" status
set(handles.status,'String','Working');

%--empty some edit text
set(handles.misklasifikasi,'String','');
set(handles.nilaiakurasi,'String','');
set(handles.nilaiwaktu,'String','');

%--Some computation process

%--Giving the result
set(handles.misklasifikasi,'String',misklasifikasi);
set(handles.nilaiakurasi,'String',sprintf('%g%% ',akurasi));
set(handles.nilaiwaktu,'String',sprintf('%g detik ',waktu));

%--give the program ready status 
set(handles.status,'String','Ready');
```

but when I try it the program like just do the command after the computation process, did I missed something???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a `drawnow` just before you start the computation. This will force MATLAB to flush the GUI event queue. You want to also place another call at the end of the callback function.